# Yii2: actionView() in controller is called 2 times

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am developing Yii2 project and I need to count page views, which must be stored in database. I have necessary field in MySql. I was trying to update this field, when actionView() of my controller is called everytime. And it worked, the value of the field is updating. But the weird thing is that actionView() works twice.
Here is actionView code:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->view_amount++;
    $model->save();
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

and the screenshot of debug data
[image: debug data]

as you can see, the same action works twice at the same time, so the count of views works incorrectly. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think, there is anything wrong with code snippet above. You should check implementation.

Comment: i don't think there is any problem, but you can try `$model->save(false)` may be that will work other wise check your implementation

Comment: thank you, guys! the problem was in jquery plugin, which I used in view file.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the debug toolbar/debugging and try again, most likely you're loading the requested page once again for debug purposes.